# Why doesn't this XSS attack work?

Tags: xss

I want to inject some XSS code into a site. The source code is like this:

```
<span class="c_red">"aaa"</span>
```

The word `aaa` is displayed on the screen.

Then I injected some shellcode into the searchbox. The code I inputed is like this:

```
</span><img src=* onerror=alert(1) /><span>"
```

So, the result code is

```
<span class="c_red">"</span><img src=* onerror=alert(1) /><span>""</span>
```

Why can't I get the alert box on the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide enough informations about the problem, but I think it may be caused by:

1. The website you are trying to inject uses [Str_Replace](http://php.net/str_replace) or different method to replace some characters from your code, rendering it useless.
2. You placed your image out of span, possibly forcing the server operator to ignore your code.

Try checking the source code of website (CTRL+U), and look if your injected code is in the source code, and if its not highlighted by red color (that means the part is not correctly typed, and will be ignored by some browsers)

Comment: Yeah, thx. I just checked the source code following the method you supplied and found the char like '<', '>' was encoded like '&gt', '&lt'. So the website has done something validated in output, but the encoded char cannot be showed in FireBug. Is that OK what I thought?

Comment: If the website encoded characters to &gt and &lt, it means that it's also using http://php.net/htmlentities or http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php, and yes, FireBug may not know the characters.